# Escopo em chamada assíncrona (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, assincronismo, callback

Vamos supor que eu tivesse o seguinte método:

```
this.loadCustomers = function(){
    Request.get("php/loadCustomersAction.php", (function(error, data){
        if(!error)
            this.setCustomers(data);
    }).bind(this));
};
```

onde "Request.get" é um método que realiza chamadas assíncronas.

É possível imaginar que o "this" em

```
this.setCustomers()
```

possa manter o mesmo escopo de

```
this.loadCustomers()
```

sem a ajuda do bind ao estabelecer o callback e sem tornar a função síncrona? Se sim, como poderia ser feito?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Há maneiras de dar a volta a isso sem usar o `.bind`, mas lembra-te que pode ser o caso de o `.bind` ser o mais util/simples mesmo.

**Alternativas:**

- **Usando alias `var self = this`**

ie: guardando uma referência do `this`

```
this.loadCustomers = function(){
    var self = this;
    Request.get("php/loadCustomersAction.php", function(error, data){
        if(!error) self.setCustomers(data);
    });
};
```

- **Usando `() => {}`**

ie: arrow functions

```
this.loadCustomers = function(){
    Request.get("php/loadCustomersAction.php", (error, data) => {
        if(!error) this.setCustomers(data);
    });
};
```

---

Pode haver mais alternativas, mas depende de como `Req.get` é implementado. Pode valer a pena testar chamar esse `Req.get` forçando o contexto:

```
this.loadCustomers = function(){
    Request.get.call(this, "php/loadCustomersAction.php", function (error, data){
        if(!error) this.setCustomers(data);
    });
};
```

que com alguma sorte permite, se a implementação permitir, passar o contexto para a callback.

Comment: Acabei optando pelo uso do bind, mesmo. Me pareceu a forma menos arriscada de trabalhar. Obrigado!